# Create custom UITableView header with white text and red background

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView that needs a simple custom header that has a background color and a white label. This is my code:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *titleString = @"Title";

    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 45)];
    [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:headerView.frame];


    headerLabel.text = titleString;
    headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [headerView addSubview:headerLabel];

    return headerView;
}
```

I can change the background color without any problem, but for some reason **the label always shows gray text color**. I'm also using a custom category to change all fonts to a custom one that looks like this (I don't think this is the problem but anyway..):

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyFont" size:self.font.pointSize]];
}

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    id result = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (result) {
        [self setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyFont" size:self.font.pointSize]];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Any idea why could this be happening?

Comment: try to create your headerView and your UILabel in viewDidLoad. and in viewForHeaderInSection do only: return headerView

Comment: Why don't you use just a UILabel since its inherited from UIView ?

Comment: @Mutawe I also tried that and happened the same.

Comment: @Ilario can't do that since I don't have only one header, I have a lot of sections.

Comment: Your code works for me, both in a device, and in the simulator. At least, in iOS 7.

Comment: @neutrino I'm using XCode 5.0.2 and also trying on iOS 7 and can't make it work. Strange...

Comment: do you get the same result if you rebuild and run your project without using your custom category?

Comment: The only difference is that I'm not using your category to set a custom font... Have you tried without that?

Comment: are you disabling the label somewhere? _doesn't seem so but still_

Comment: @staticVoidMan Actually it is the category problem! I deleted it and now it works. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: i don't know and i don't think it has anything to do with it but try removing `-(void)awakeFromNib` from the category and check again. is there any more code in the category?

Comment: If i remove initWithFrame and keeping awakeFromNib it works, but obviously I now have to set my custom font to all the fonts that I was initializing from code. Not too much work but I still don't understand why is this happening. Strange.